# Linear Optimization with Ratio of Constraint Variables

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I found a similar question at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/413317 but I could not comprehend the explanation. I am required to optimize the sale for the following question:

> 

There are two kinds of tea. There is 100 Kg of tea kind (A) and 70 Kg of tea kind (B). If we combine the two kinds with ratio of 4 to 3 (A to B) the result (product $T_{1}$) can be sold at 1200 per Kg and if we combine the two kinds with ratio of 3 to 5, it (product $T_{2}$) can be sold at 2000 per Kg. Maximize the sale.

> 

If $x_{i}$ represents the amount of tea A and B for $i=1,2$ respectively, we have $\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}=\frac{4}{3}$ and $\frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}=\frac{3}{5}$ for product $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ respectively. Let $y_{i}$ denote the amount of $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ respectively. Then clearly we have $y_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{2}x_{i}$. Are these constraints true?
$$
0\leq x_{i}\quad\text{for}\quad i=1,2\\x_{1}\leq100\wedge x_{2}\leq70\\4x_{1}+3x_{2}\leq170\\3x_{1}+5x_{2}\leq170
$$
I am pretty sure that they are false, because the value of optimal point given by them makes no sense. Could you point out where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Once you specify the values of $y_1$ and $y_2$, the required amount of each tea is determined by the recipes.  The problem is to maximize
$$1200y_1+2000y_2$$ subject to
\begin{align}
\frac{4}{7}y_1 + \frac{3}{8}y_2 &\le 100 \\
\frac{3}{7}y_1 + \frac{5}{8}y_2 &\le 70 \\
y_1 &\ge 0 \\
y_2 &\ge 0 \\
\end{align}
It turns out that the first constraint is redundant, as you can see by multiplying the second constraint by $4/3$:
$$
\frac{4}{7}y_1 + \frac{3}{8}y_2
= \frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{3}{7}y_1 + \frac{9}{32}y_2\right)
\le \frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{3}{7}y_1 + \frac{5}{8}y_2\right) \le \frac{4}{3}\cdot70 < 100$$
The feasible region thus has three extreme points: $(0,0)$, $(490/3,0)$, and $(0,112)$.  The last of these is optimal.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kuz8pwzmub

Comment: How did you arrive at these constraints? Why is the first equation less than 100 and the second less than 70?

Comment: And the answer which your equations conduce is $(184.55,-14.55)$, yes minus! Which makes no sense at all.

Comment: The first constraint enforces that the amount of tea A used can be no more than its supply of $100$ kg. The second constraint is similar for tea B. The third and fourth constraints explicitly impose that the variables are nonnegative, so how did you get $y_2=-14.55$?

Comment: Easy. Just drew them in Cartesian Coordinate system

Comment: Your picture should be the shaded region determined by the four inequalities, not just two lines.  And the optimal solution will occur at one of the corner points of the region.